# How to ignore right click on Easel JS

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, mouseevent, addeventlistener, easeljs

I am working on Easel JS and came across one issue.
If I am adding Events to one easelJs element then how can I ignore the right-click and only listen to left-click?

Click should work on a primary key but it is also working for other keys also.
I have come across one scenario where pressUp of left-clicking is getting missed and that is creating an issue.
steps are as follows:

1. left mouseDown on the object.
2. right mouseDown on the same object.
3. right pressUp on the object.

If we follow this order, left pressUp is getting missed it is not getting fired nor it is present after that point. It's like it totally vanishes as if it never existed.

Can anyone please help me with this? Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I am kind confused with your question, but I think a easy way to ignore the right click event is to use `event.preventDefault` for `contextmenu`.

> The preventDefault() method of the Event interface tells the user
> agent that if the event does not get explicitly handled, its default
> action should not be taken as it normally would be.

For example (you may not able to show the right click menu in the example):

```js
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  return false;

})
```

Comment: if cancellable is false then preventDefault will not work.
I have tried this and it didn't work.
if left mouse button is down and then we did right mouseDown then on onPressUp of right button whole cycle of events of left button is getting erased
for eg. if i did left mouseDown => right mouseDown => rightPressUp (works fine till now) => left pressUp at this point left onPressUp doest't get fired. it is like we never did left mouseDown and gets stuck.

It is not an issue with javascript. It is an issue of easelJs.

Comment: @ShubhamShinde, will a click function that only check left mouse click be helpful?

Comment: nope! That is another thing with easelJs. Click gets triggered on both primary and secondary button.

Comment: @ShubhamShinde, generally I am kind confused with the question, so you have a button that contain a child button? It will be easier for me if you could provide some codes that you are deal with. We are not dealing with word problem

Comment: primary means left button of mouse and secondary  right button of mouse.

Comment: @ShubhamShinde, well, understand now. There does have ways to check whether primary and secondary button is being clicked when click event is triggered, but why won 't it be helpful

Comment: if i have these 3 events on item.
`
item.addEventListener('mousedown', this._onMouseDown);
item.addEventListener('pressmove', this._onPressMove);
item.addEventListener('pressup', this._onPressUp)
`
then these event will get fired on mouse interaction.
if i follow sequence
left mouseDown on the item.
right mouseDown on the same item.
right pressUp on the item.
my left mouse button is still down and after this if i do move the mouse then press move should get fired and if i release the left mouse button then press up should get fired but that is not happening in here.